# Draw.io - copy/paste table from excel to draw.io with individual texts

Tags: draw.io

I have tables in excel and I'd like to copy/paste them into draw.io table. Is there any way I can make all rows into individual rows (texts) in draw.io instead of copy/paste each row (text) from excel to draw.io?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

[image: The Plus icon > Advance > CSV]

Click the Plus + icon on the toolbar above the canvas.
Go to Advanced > CSV

There Just after the First 4 lines of comments (starting with '##'),
Replace everything, and add your list items. Click Import.

For learning how to change further styles, configs etc., read the help items in the text that was written by default in the box (which you replaced from 4th line). Or see here https://drawio-app.com/import-from-csv-to-drawio/.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot copy the data in an editable way. However, you can get a snapshot of the data as a picture, and then paste that in the draw.io drawing.

- Go to Excel spreadsheet, and highlight the data you want to insert into the graph
- Select the "Home" tab in the toolbar
- Click on the down arrow next to the copy button on the toolbar
- Select "Copy as picture..."
  [image: copy as picture]
- Select whether you want copy as shown on screen or as printed
  [[image: Copy as printed or screen][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lq6h4.png)
- Go to draw.io and paste image of selected data

Answer (score 0):

Basically it is not something fully supported but in some cases copy/paste might work but use keyboard shortcuts.

Other possible solutions are to try to export as HTML/CSV and import it to draw.io

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can easily paste a part of table from microsoft excel and google sheet to
draw.io by 'crtl+c, crtl+v' creating a new table. It will be created with style "text;whiteSpace=wrap;html=1;" and then can be edited as a natively created draw.io table with actions like "create new column left" and so on.

Comment: I can't get this to work from google sheets.

Comment: Excel does seem to work, with some massaging, but google sheets doesn't seem to work at all.

Comment: this worked for me in Macbook and using Google Sheets - but i had to use the macbook keyboard and not my external keyboard. I used command+c, command+v

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use sql scripts for this.

- -> Advance -> SQL .

I created sql scripts with excel formula and paste them here.

also please make sure you place the cursor properly , so that tables dont get overlapped.

Comment: Could you gibe an example of the script? and the result?